# Build dynamic list in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to dynamically create some aws resources in terraform making use of count and then build an output variable containing a list of all created resource ids

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  // If subnet_id value is supplied then we set count to 1 to create otherwise skip
  count = "${replace(replace(var.primary_subnet_cidr, "/^.+/", "1"), "/^$/", "0")}"
  tags = {
    Name = "subnet-1"
  }
  cidr_block = "${var.primary_subnet_cidr}"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
}
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-2" {
  // If subnet_id value is supplied then we set count to 1 to create otherwise skip
  count = "${replace(replace(var.secondary_subnet_cidr, "/^.+/", "1"),"/^$/", "0")}"
  tags = {
    Name = "subnet-2"
  }
  cidr_block = "${var.secondary_subnet_cidr}"
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}b"
}

output "ids" {
      value = ["${aws_subnet.subnet-1.id}","${aws_subnet.subnet-2.id}"]
}
```

The idea is to create only the subnet you want by supplying its variable (primary_subnet_cidr or secondary_subnet_cidr).

Creating them dynamically works fine however my issue is with the dynamic list.

When attempting to use this list in something like a `aws_db_subnet_group.subnet_ids` which takes in a list, it only works if both subnets have been created otherwise it throws me the following error

`InvalidSubnet: Subnet IDs are required.`

I have also tried this

```
output "ids" {
      value = ["${aws_subnet.*.id}"]
}
```

But terraform does not seem to support wildcards on resource level.

I suspect this has to do with the way I generated the output list. Is there a better way to generate that dynamic list so it includes only the created resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but you need to use the correct Terraform resource syntax of `RESOURCE-TYPE.RESOURCE-NAME.PROPERTY_NAME` or `RESOURCE-TYPE.RESOURCE-NAME.*.PROPERTY_NAME`. So, in your example, you would output:

```
output "ids" {
   value = "${aws_subnet.subnet-1.*.id}"
}
```

Of course, you may want to join the two lists using the [concat interpolation function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#concat-list1-list2-):

```
output "ids" {
   value = "${concat(aws_subnet.subnet-1.*.id, aws_subnet.subnet-2.*.id)}"
}
```

But if your `count` property is set to 0 on either resource, this might throw an error. To remedy that, you can use some combination of other interpolation functions (e.g. `coalescelist()`), but I'm afraid I can't remember the exact combination.

Finally, for your `count` properties, these var definitions are a little tricky to read. Here are some other ideas to try:

```
// Count = 1 if var.secondary_subnet_cidr is non-empty
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  count = "${signum(length(var.secondary_subnet_cidr))}"
  ...
}

// Define a separate var altogether. Ideally, you could infer this, but sometimes it's the best you can do.
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  count = "${var.should_create_secondary_subnet)}"
  ...
}
```

**Update Jun 6, 2017:** Thanks to @MartinAtkins for pointing out that as of Terraform 0.9.x, you no longer need to wrap list outputs in `[` and `]`. I've updated my answer.

**Update Jun 8, 2017:** To select only the non-empty list out of two lists where one may be empty, use `${element(concat(aws_subnet.subnet-1.*.id, aws_subnet.subnet-2.*.id), 0)}`. The `concat()` function will accept an empty list, and the `element(..., 0)` will always returns the first element, which in this case is the non-empty list.

Comment: As of Terraform 0.9.6, the brackets wrapping the "splat variables" are no longer needed nor recommended, since they will be phased out in some future version. What's here will work for the time being, though! :D

Comment: `aws_subnet.subnet-1.*.id` does not exist afaik. The correct syntax should be `aws_subnet.subnet-1.id` therefore my attempt at getting a list of all id attributes from all resources doing `aws_subnet.*.id` but that does not work. Thanks for the tips on the coalescelist and the syntax. It is exactly that interpolation function combination I am looking after. I am thinking the error I am getting may be due to an empty value in the list when count = 0 for one of the resources. Maybe `compact` might solve the issue. I'll try it out later.

Comment: Trying to read from a non-existing list becuase `count = 0` is a common situation. If I remember how we hack around that, I will update my response!

Comment: Ok, I found it. It's `${element(concat(aws_subnet.subnet-1.*.id, aws_subnet.subnet-2.*.id), 0)}`. The `concat()` function will accept an empty list, and the `element(..., 0)` will always returns the first element, which in this case is the non-empty list. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I wanted a way to get a list of the created resource ids so the user can supply subnet-1 and/or subnet-2 so element wouldn't have worked however removing element and just running concat worked just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found this question while trying to create a dynamic list, where I had to create a list with a variable number of elements in the list. I was creating a list of strings. I solved the problem by using [Terraform's `compact` method](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/compact.html). Basically, this list would filter out blank elements I generated inside my list.

For example suppose I have the following list,

```
myList = ["foo", barExists ? "bar" : ""]
```

This will create either `["foo", "bar"]` or `["foo", ""]`. If you instead need either `["foo", "bar"]` or `["foo"]`, the compact function is your friend.

```
myList = compact(["foo", barExists ? "bar" : ""])
```

For such cases, the above line will work.

Comment: Wow what a life saver! Thank you, this is awesome.